# While creating sales order system will get hanging in ax 2012

Tags: axapta

While creating sales order system will get hanging and i tried to add records manually in sales Table that time also system will get hang.please give me some suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The description is not very informative, my bet - it's database locks.
Causes are many, additional info may help.
Look to SQL Activity monitor. If it's it, try to determine blocking session.